# Find all positive differentiable functions $f$ that satisfy $\int_0^x \sin(t) f(t) dt = [f(x)]^2-1$for all real numbers $x$.

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

Find all positive differentiable functions $f$ that satisfy$$\int_0^x \sin(t) f(t) dt = [f(x)]^2-1$$for all real numbers $x$.

I know this question has been answered here: [Proof for differentiable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905570/proof-for-differentiable-functions), but I'm still a little confused about parts of the solution. I mostly followed along hamam_Abdallah's solution. I mainly do not understand why we need to first differentiate both sides to get $f(x)sin(x)=2f(x)f'(x)$ if we're trying to go backwards from integration.

Sorry in advance if this is very basic; I don't have much background in integration!

Comment: The idea is to use the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: "we're trying to go backwards from integration", not quite. You want to solve for $f(x)$, and you can isolate the function by differentiating, so this is why you do this. In general, when you have an integral equation like this you differentiate to transform the question into solving a differential equation instead, since the methods to solve the latter equations are commonly taught.